# Как указать и записать в строку путь к директории в WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть строка, в которую записывается путь к директории. Путь указывать должен пользователь. Например, при нажатии на кнопку открывается окно Windows с директориями.
Пробую с OpenFileDialog, но не понимаю - требует файл указать. А необходим только путь к папке.

Comment: [FolderBrowserDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать FolderBrowserDialog

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string folderPath = "";
            FolderBrowserDialog directchoosedlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (directchoosedlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                folderPath = directchoosedlg.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
```